# display validation error message next to the textbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm newbie to codeigniter.I want to display the error message next to the text box.My view file `create.php` contains the following code.

```
  <?php     
    echo validation_errors();               //validation
    echo form_open('news/create');  //create a form   
  ?>
 <div class="boxes">
   <div class="common">
     <div class="lables">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
     </div>

     <div class="text_boxes">
        <input type="text" name="uname" /><div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message;?></br>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And below is my controller model:

```
 public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Insert Items';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','required|min_length[6]|max_length[15]');
    $this->data['message'] = enter your name;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uaddress','enter your address','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Enter emailid','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Enter mobile number','required');

     if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->news_model->set_news();
        $this->load->view('news/success');
    }
    /** View Details **/
    $data['user_data'] = $this->news_model->get_details();
    $data['title'] = 'Database Details';

    $this->load->view('templates/header');   //used to call the view file(header) which is in templates/header
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);         //used to call the view file(index) ie:news/index
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');              //used to call the view file(footer) ie:templates/header
    /**     END **/
}
```

But I know `#infoMessage` will always show after the `username field` . But I really don't know how to display the error message in custom place.

Kindly help me to solve this!!

Edit: After i add

```
 <input type="text" name="uname"  value="<?php echo set_value('uname'); ?>" />
  <div id="infoMessage"><?php echo form_error('uname'); ?></div></br>
```

this code show like the below image:

[image: My output]

Comment: Some one please say the answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [CI documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually)  you could find the answer.

Replace your line with this

```
<input type="text" name="uname"  value="<?php echo set_value('uname'); ?>" /><div id="infoMessage"><?php echo form_error('uname'); ?></div></br>
```

Comment: And also i want to display separate error message when the field is empty and then name is below 6 characters & above 15

Comment: I just want to remove the list of errors...it will be enough

Comment: in that case remove `echo validation_errors(); `  at the top of page.It displaying your all errors together.

Answer (score 0):

echo validation_errors();  ----   take this out prints everything.

Put echo form_error('YOUR_FIELD_NAME'); after each input field with field names.